# Show url image if it exist in database. If url empty show another picture

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have two images in a listview. However, one image I fetch from a database but not all items in the list has a picture in the database.

I tried putting Visible statements in XAML and then add some logic in my model with out any luck. See code:

My two images:

```
 <u:CircleLabelSmall  IsVisible="{Binding hideImage}"                                                        Text="{Binding PersonName, Converter={StaticResource NameConverter}}"
BadgeColor="{Binding PersonName, Converter={StaticResource NameColorConverter}}" />

<d:CircleImage Source="{Binding adImage}"  IsVisible="{Binding showImage}">                                                      
</d:CircleImage>
```

This string fetches the image from database:

```
public string adImage { get; set; }
```

Here is my attemped try on making it work in my Model:

```
public bool isImageUrlNull { get { return!string.IsNullOrEmpty(adImage); } }
public string adImage { get; set; }
```

Appreciate any tip available :) Thanks

Comment: Did you solved it?

Comment: No, I updated my XAML so i think that is good now. I added the code from the answer below but it shows both the pictures now. @AndroDevil

Comment: Why dont you put the two images in grid? One above another

Comment: Doesn't matter. They should never be visible at the same time for each row in the listview anyway. @AndroDevil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way would be using a convertor and returning the `Source` based on conditions:

```
public class ImageSourceConvertor: IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {

      if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value.ToString())){

           return "DefaultImage";
       }
      return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Check the following post at the Microsoft docs to understand how converters work: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/converters

Goodluck

Revert if you have any queries

Comment: Thanks, I made a new file and added the ImageSourceConvertor converter. I'm not sure how to get my XAML going since I do not bind the source from one of the pictures. I would have to use Isvisible from my understanding? @FreakyAli

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by ` I do not bind the source from one of the pictures` can you please elaborate as of right now I can see that you are using `Binding` for your `ImageSource`, am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: In my xaml I have ```<u:CircleLabelSmall``` which really is not an image. Its just designed to look like an image, so there is no ```Source=""``` on it. So I would have to use the IsVisible along with the Converter? @FreakyAli

Comment: Yes, you can do that as well :) Sorry I did not understand that earlier

Comment: I updated my XAML in my question. Would that work with the converter code that you wrote? @FreakyAli

Comment: Yes it should just return the correct Boolean from the convertor...

Comment: I added the new XAML (like in my edited question) and your Converter in a new file but it shows both the pictures. Also added namespace and `<c:ImageSourceConverter x:Key="whichImage" />`in XAML. @FreakyAli

Comment: Can you debug and see if you are returning the correct boolean from the convertor?

Comment: Its not running the code in the converter at all when I set breakpoints on a few places in your code. @FreakyAli

Comment: Umm, can you add your current code into the question so that I can take a look?

Comment: Updated. Everything after "EDIT" is what i added. @FreakyAli

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200345/discussion-between-freakyali-and-petterandersson).

Answer (score 0):

use "FFImageLoading" nougat package for any image url direct in your xml with default placehoder

add namespace in xaml

> xmlns:forms="clr-namespace:FFImageLoading.Forms;assembly=FFImageLoading.Forms"

```
<forms:CachedImage
      Aspect="AspectFill"
      LoadingPlaceholder="placeholderimageName"
      Source="{Binding YourImage}" />
```

for more detail show this [link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.FFImageLoading/)

Comment: This is not what im asking for. I want picture number 1 to be visible only if the databse image is null... @Dharam